# Error while changing the compileskdversion (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been working on a Xamarin Forms app since December 2019, and I've been updating my Xamarin Forms so I can keep it up and running with the latest features. This was fine until Xamarin 5 was released. This version asks me to change my compileskdversion from 9 or lower to at least 10, so I did.

My app runs smoothly with Android 9.0 (Pie) and Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1821 (latest before 5.0.0.1874 official release version) The moment I change my SDK and try to run it on my physical phone it throws me this 2 errors:

> Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido Error XARDF7023: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.class'. en System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data) en System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost) en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask()
>
> Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
> Error XARDF7024: System.IO.IOException: El nombre de archivo, el
> nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son
> correctos. en System.IO.Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
> maybeFullPath) en System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
> String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
> throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data) en
> System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
> recursive, Boolean checkHost) en
> Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask()

(sorry if some parts of the error comes in Spanish).

These errors only occur when I update the SDK. I've tried the following:

1. Clean and rebuilt
2. Install some .NET Compilers in my Xamarin Android Project
3. Install the Xamarin.AndroidX dependencies (works fine with Android 9 (Pie))
4. Use another machine to compile
5. Change phone
6. Remove old dependencies

I don't even know where to look with this error, but would appreciate any insights from the community. Thank you.

Comment: Is this error happening at compile time? Are you running from a Windows PC? If so, I have seen a similar error when there is a Path-Limit violation. Create a folder in `C:\Code` and copy and paste your project here. Try building from there.

Comment: well that worked better than I would expect. So now I'm going to change my default folder for my project.

Comment: @CesarDanielRangelHernandez are you still having this problem